# PGPlugin class PGBatteryLevelPlugin (pluginName: com.phonegap.battery) does not exist?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi all I'm trying the event chapter from phonegap and when I look for battery issues it give the log as
`2011-11-22 11:30:17.964 Event[644:207] ERROR: Plugin 'com.phonegap.battery' not found, or is not a PGPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in PhoneGap.plist.`

And when i map the `com.phonegap.battery` in the plist with value `PGBatteryLevelPlugin` then the log is

`2011-11-22 11:18:03.152 Event[552:207] PGPlugin class PGBatteryLevelPlugin (pluginName: com.phonegap.battery) does not exist.
2011-11-22 11:18:03.152 Event[552:207] ERROR: Plugin 'com.phonegap.battery' not found, or is not a PGPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in PhoneGap.plist.`

Any idea what to do? I have downloaded the plugins for phonegap but couldn't found the battery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no battery plugin for PhoneGap.  The thing you're trying to look for is actually part of a tutorial written up at [wiki.phonegap.com](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43708792/How%20to%20Install%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS).  I don't think it's a real plug-in.

Do another Google search on "Phone Gap" + "battery" and you might find something more useful.

Like this one I just found:  https://github.com/alunny/phonegap-battery-status

Comment: Yeah I have downloaded this plugin, Actually I have just started learning PhoneGap and thus was trying its all tutorial. But unfortunately battery events are not being fired. +1 for your ans, will accept answer when there is no exact answer for this.